# Ampps: imagick: Unable to initialize module windows 10 64bit/php 7

Tags: php, windows, imagemagick

I use Ampps version 3.5

in here
[Link](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)
I install `ImageMagick-7.0.1-6-Q16-x64-dll.exe`

(and set php path)

after that in:

https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.4.2/windows

I downloaded 7.0 `Thread Safe (TS) x64` and copy

```
php_imagick.dll
```

to

```
F:\Ampps\php\ext
```

after that I add `extension=php_imagick.dll` to php.ini
then I restart apache...

but It not be install (I checked it with phpinfo())

---

also I do top steps for x86 imagick version...

what is my wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution ? I'm stuck with the same error. Imagick is correctly installed but not the php extension

Comment: @Sébastien I could run it with xampps 32bit,But not with ampps,I tried all version...I think ampps is better than xampps,So I rather use 'https://github.com/Intervention/image' with GD,I hope help you too...